# Facebook Graph API - get latest comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to parse fb feed to find new comments. First I get posts list by this url `http://graph.facebook.com/2.0/page_id/posts`. Then I get comments by `http://graph.facebook.com/2.0/page_id/post_id/comments` for each post. I found that I can use `batch_requests` and `http://graph.facebook.com/2.0/page_id/posts?fields=comments`. But I want to ask:

1. Can I get and parse only new comments? Not for all existing posts. Can I get response sorted by latest comments?
2. If no, what should I do in next case - Comment for post isn't included in fb/posts because this post created 250 posts before?

P.S. FQL is not good solution because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify an order of `reverse_chronological` to get the newest comments first. It's not documented but seems to work from `v2.0` on.

i.e. Get all post comments w/ newest first

```
[post_id]/comments?filter=stream&order=reverse_chronological
```

Answer (score 5):

1. No, you can not get new comments only and you need to do the sorting on your own too.
2. Store the comments in a database. You can go through all comments, the new ones should be the first ones, check the comment ID in your database. If the comment ID is already in the database, stop getting more comments. Alternatively, you could also just store the latest comment ID somewhere instead of all comments.

Comment: I like your idea, but I am staring at comments coming out of the API now that are not in chronological order. In fact, the reference does give you the option to sort chronologically, however you must then take the comments oldest first. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments

Comment: This query {post-id}/comments?order=chronological SHOULD return them in order. And, at first glance, it does. However, I have results right now that puts a comment on 2015-04-07 before 2015-05-01 while earlier records have 2015-06-05 at the top. So, have fun.

Comment: afaik the comments do come in chronological order. the newest ones first. if not, file a bug.